# blazor render fragment doesn't refresh

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a modal component in Blazor and it is possible to use it  many times in a page, so when I use it more than one time in a page, for the second time the data doesn't refresh and it still shows the old data from first modal so it always shows me the Hello for all modal in the page, here is the Modal Component

```html
     @inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime
    
    <dialog id="@ElementIds.Modal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-box w-11/12 max-w-2xl">
            <div class="modal-action" style="margin: 10px">
                <form id="@ElementIds.ModalClose" method="dialog">
                    <!-- if there is a button, it will close the modal -->
                    <button class="btn btn-circle">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="Close">
                            <path d="M12,2C6.5,2,2,6.5,2,12s4.5,10,10,10s10-4.5,10-10S17.5,2,12,2z M15.7,14.3c0.4,0.4,0.4,1,0,1.4c-0.4,0.4-1,0.4-1.4,0
                                    L12,13.4l-2.3,2.3c-0.4,0.4-1,0.4-1.4,0c-0.4-0.4-0.4-1,0-1.4l2.3-2.3L8.3,9.7c-0.4-0.4-0.4-1,0-1.4c0.4-0.4,1-0.4,1.4,0l2.3,2.3
                                    l2.3-2.3c0.4-0.4,1-0.4,1.4,0c0.4,0.4,0.4,1,0,1.4L13.4,12L15.7,14.3z" fill="#717af7" class="color000000 svgShape"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
    
            <div class="h-full px-3 pb-4 overflow-y-auto ">
                @Content
            </div>
    
    
        </div>
    </dialog>
```

```cs
    @code {
        [Parameter]
        public  RenderFragment? Content { get; set; }
        
        internal static class ElementIds
        {
            public static Guid Modal { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();
            public static Guid ModalClose { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
        
        public void ShowModal()
        {
            _ = JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("eval", $"document.getElementById('{ElementIds.Modal}').showModal()");
        }
        
        public void CloseModal()
        {
            _= JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("eval", $"document.getElementById('{ElementIds.ModalClose}').submit()");
       

     }
    }
```

and for example, I use it like this (it's an example and sometimes I put table or form inside the modal)

```html
    <button @onclick="()=>_modalRef.ShowModal()" class="btn avatar" style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;right: 40px; background: red">click</button>
    <Modal @ref="@_modalRef">
        <Content >
            <h1>hello</h1>
        </Content>
    </Modal>
    
    <button @onclick="()=>_modalRef.ShowModal()" class="btn avatar" style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;right: 40px; background: red">click</button>
    <Modal @ref="@_modalRef">
        <Content >
            <h1>hello message 1</h1>
        </Content>
    </Modal>
```

```cs
    
    @code{
    
        private Modal _modalRef;
    
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this is an adequate example. Seems like the obvious solution would be to refresh the data before you want to show "new" data. Your example is just static content so there is nothing to be "refreshed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly have IDs for the component but they are incorrectly declared as `static`. That means all `<Modal>` components will share the same IDs.

```
internal class ElementIds
{
    public Guid Modal { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public Guid ModalClose { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}

private ElementIds ElementIds { get; } = new();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sample  has 2 Modal components but they both have the same @ref.

This might work:

```html
  <button @onclick="()=>_modalRef1.ShowModal()" ...>click</button>
    <Modal @ref="@_modalRef1">
        <Content >
            <h1>hello</h1>
        </Content>
    </Modal>
    
    <button @onclick="()=>_modalRef2.ShowModal()" ...>click</button>
    <Modal @ref="@_modalRef2">
        <Content >
            <h1>hello message 1</h1>
        </Content>
    </Modal>
```

```cs
@code{
    
  private Modal _modalRef1, _modalRef2;
    
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it still shows the data of first modal for second modal

Comment: Yes, I see another problem. See second answer.